# Missing value of column based on date comparison sql

Tags: sql, sas

Need help in getting this logic side. I am using two fields in a table.

```
DATE                RATE
31DEC2014           .    
31DEC2015           .    
31DEC2016           .    
31DEC2017           0.1600
31DEC2018           0.1700
31DEC2019           0.1770
```

I want to populate the `RATE` equal of first non missing `RATE` like below with condition when `DATE > 31DEC2017`

```
DATE                RATE
31DEC2014           0.1600    
31DEC2015           0.1600    
31DEC2016           0.1600    
31DEC2017           0.1600
31DEC2018           0.1700
31DEC2019           0.1770
```

This has to be done in SAS PROC SQL.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont like to use PROC SQL for this

```
data have;
input DATE:date9. RATE;
format DATE date9.;
datalines;
31DEC2014 .    
31DEC2015 .    
31DEC2016 .    
31DEC2017 0.1600
31DEC2018 0.1700
31DEC2019 0.1770
;

proc sql;
   create table want as
   select DATE, 
          case rate
             when . then (select rate from have(where=(rate))
                          having date=min(date))
             else rate
          end as rate
   from have;
quit;
```

Answer (score 2):

This is rather complicated in proc sql.  As a `select`:

```
select t.*,
       coalesce(t.rate, tt.rate) as imputed_rate
from t join
     (select t.*
      from t join
           (select min(date) as min_date
            from t t2
            where rate is not null
           ) tt
           on t.date = tt.min_date
     ) td;
```

This would be quite simple in a data set using `retain`.

Answer (score 1):

You can perform a correlated sub-query to obtain the imputed `rate` as the `rate` from the next `date` with a `rate`.

Example:

Data expanded to include groups and multiple gaps.

```
data have;
attrib date informat=date9. format=date9.;
input bankid date rate; datalines;
1 31DEC2014           .    
1 31DEC2015           .    
1 31DEC2016           .    
1 31DEC2017           0.1600
1 31DEC2018           0.1700
1 31DEC2019           0.1770
1 31DEC2020           .
1 31DEC2021           0.1250
2 31DEC2014           0.1990
2 31DEC2015           .    
2 31DEC2016           .    
2 31DEC2017           .
2 31DEC2018           0.1700
2 31DEC2019           0.1770
2 31DEC2020           .
2 31DEC2021           0.1250

;

proc sql;
  create table want as
  select 
    have.*,
    case 
      when not missing(rate) then rate
      else (select rate from have as future
            where 
            future.bankid = outer.bankid 
            and future.rate is not null
            and future.date > outer.date
            having future.date = min(future.date)
            )
    end as imputed_rate
  from
    have as outer
  ;
quit;
```

Answer (score 0):

For completeness, here is a data step approach

```
data want(drop=r);
   do until (rate);
      set have;
      r = rate;
   end;
   do until (z);
      set have end=z;
      if rate = . then rate=r;
      output;
   end;
run;
```